# How do I get the base URL of My Web Application?

Tags: c#, iis-7

Is it possible to get the base URL of a web site hosted in IIS 7 by using `Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager`?

In the simplest scenario, this would be:

```
http://localhost
```

but I need to get it programmatically.

If I can't use `ServerManager` what is the best alternative?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `string baseURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host`.

Comment: @Joe.Net: I hope this was helpful

Comment: @Joe.Net: U r welcome joe. Happy to know my answer was helpful.

Comment: This only works if you have a request from a browser client at your disposal. If you need to know the URL(s) the site is being hosted at before the site is browsed to by users (as in my unfortunate case) then you'll need to use an alternative method of establishing the URL.

Answer (score 17):

For those interested in the usage of Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager, here's some code. Consider that an IIS application my have more than one binding, resulting in more than one URL per web application.

```
var siteName = "Default Web Site";
var appPath = "MyWebApplication";

var serverManager = new ServerManager();
var site = serverManager.Sites[siteName];
appPath = appPath.StartsWith("/") ? appPath : "/" + appPath;
var app = site.Applications[appPath];

var urls = new List<string>();

foreach (var binding in site.Bindings)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(binding.Protocol);
    sb.Append("://");
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(binding.Host))
    {
        sb.Append(binding.Host);
    }
    else
    {
        if (Equals(binding.EndPoint.Address, IPAddress.Any))
        {
            sb.Append("localhost");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(binding.EndPoint.Address);
        }
    }

    if (binding.EndPoint.Port != 80)
    {
        sb.Append(":");
        sb.Append(binding.EndPoint.Port);
    }

    sb.Append(app.Path);
    urls.Add(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: It turns out that this is actually not what the OP was interested in. Did you notice the OP marked the `HttpContext.Current` answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: Well that's why I introduced the answer with "for those interested...". You see, many people come here looking for an answer regarding ServerManager, so I think this might be helpful.

Comment: That's not how it works. An answer about ServerManager should be an answer to a _question_ about ServerManager.

Comment: But it is a question about ServerManager, isn't it? You asked how to get the base URL of a site using ServerManager.

Comment: No, it's not. The OP _thought_ it was a question about ServerManager. It was not. Please read the accepted answer to see what the real question was about.

Comment: Ok, I'm willing to learn. What would be the best alternative for me if I see such a thread? I guess many people would come to this thread because they googled for ServerMenager, and the answer does not always help, since in many cases using ServerManager you are not using ASP.NET. So if I think I have an asnwer that might interest others than OP, what should I do with it?

Comment: See if you can find an actual question. Note that I edited the title to reflect what the OP was actually asking. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: Thanks very much for this! If I saw one more answer with HttpContext in it I was ready to go postal =).

Comment: John I respectfully disagree - Munir's input is valuable for cases where you don't have an HttpContext available (i.e. before users browse to your website, e.g. if you need the URL at Application_Start time, as I do in my particular case). Munir's suggestsion gives me the port and a reverse IP lookup will get me my server's FQDN, not great but the best I can do.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It answers my question about using ServerManager which is exactly what the OP asked even if it's not what the OP wanted.

Comment: This also works in Application_Start method, where you don't have a HttpRequest (when running your AppPool in integrated mode, not classic)

Comment: In general, it is incorrect to map `IPAddress.Any` to localhost. The meanings of these two IP addresses are very different.