# How to use .env variables in web.config?

Tags: vue.js, npm, iis, webpack

I'm using Vue.js and in the `public` folder there is an `index.html` file.

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
```

This `<%= BASE_URL %>` correctly resolves to the public path.  I tried putting `<%= BASE_URL %>` in a `web.config` file which is also inside the `public` folder but it doesn't recognize it.

```
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*<%= BASE_URL %>/api)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
```

This is for url rewriting on IIS.  I have different builds with different urls which is why I want it to automatically replace that.

Comment: I think this may not be possible. If it is a .net project, we can use <appSettings> to set environment variables, but the environment variables in the Vue project cannot be recognized.

Comment: "This <%= BASE_URL %> correctly resolves to the public path", it happens inside the browser, while `web.config` is strictly an item on the server side.

Comment: @LexLi No, that happens on 'npm build'

Comment: The Vue tooling called by `npm build` only manipulates browser side files by default, as Vue is a browser side framework. Not sure if you can reconfigure the tooling to manipulate `web.config`, but you might try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that the env file is for the client, and web.config for the server. I think it will not be possible to do what you want.

> WARNING
>
> Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your app!
>
> **Environment variables are embedded into the build**, meaning anyone can
> view them by inspecting your app's files.

[Modes and Environment Variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)

Look at the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925036/get-base-url-of-my-web-application/15925669), they do not say how to put the base URL in the web.config file but how to get that information in IIS